# Cache of my application increases due to Firebase UI

Tags: android, firebase, caching, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm developing an application that is about to be released by the end of this week. But I found a weird thing about my app. When I checked the app's storage info, I found that the cache data for my app is increasing rapidly when data is loading. I'm using Firebase UI to load data from Cloud Firestore into my Recycler View. This contains images too. I somehow came to the conclusion that this is all because images fetched from the server getting downloaded repeatedly, which increases my cache. I want to know how to reduce the cache size because it consumes a lot of user's storage as it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the size of the cache, you will need to set that before do any queries.  The [documentation for configuration the cache size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size) says that you can use `setCacheSizeBytes()` like this:

> When persistence is enabled, Cloud Firestore caches every document received from the backend for offline access. Cloud Firestore sets a default threshold for cache size. After exceeding the default, Cloud Firestore periodically attempts to clean up older, unused documents. You can configure a different cache size threshold or disable the clean-up process completely:

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setCacheSizeBytes(FirebaseFirestoreSettings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```